# Perlin noise not working (p5js)

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js, perlin-noise

I'm using P5.js and the Perlin `noise()` function to try and draw a circle with Perlin noise generated `x` and `y` coordinates. I don't get any error messages but nothing is drawn on the canvas. What am I doing wrong?

```js
let width;
let height;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    width = windowWidth;
    height = windowHeight;
}

var Circle = function () {
    this.x = width / 2;
    this.y = height / 2;
    this.tx = 0;
    this.ty = 0;
};

Circle.prototype.display = function () {
    stroke(0);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 200, 200);
};

Circle.prototype.walk = function () {
    this.x = map(noise(this.x), 0, 1, 0, width);
    this.y = map(noise(this.y), 0, 1, 0, height);
    this.tx += 0.01;
    this.ty += 0.01;
};

var c = new Circle();

function draw() {
    c.walk();
    c.display();
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

    </style>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: In the future, please don't delete your questions after they've been answered :)

Answer (score 1):

You should get into the habit of [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) to understand exactly what's going on. For example, I would add something like this to your `walk()` function:

```
console.log(this.x);
```

This will help you understand what's going on. You'll find out that `this.x` is always `null`. You can then trace back through the code to find out why.

Another thing that jumps out to me is that you shouldn't define your own `width` and `height` variables. Instead, use the `width` and `height` variables that P5.js provides for you.

Tracing through the code, you should also think about exactly when this line happens:

```
var c = new Circle();
```

This line of code is executed **before** the `setup()` function is called. My guess is you originally got an error saying `width` was undefined, which is why you added your own `width` variable. But that didn't really solve the problem, which is that all of this code is happening before the `setup()` function is being called.

To fix this, just move the initialization to be inside the `setup()` function:

```
var c;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
      c = new Circle();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that's exactly what happened before I defined my own width and height. This was very helpful, sorry if my question was so open-ended.